# Children route is not shown in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Children route is not shown in vuejs.

When accessing the child route, the mother route is shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    path: '/portaria',
    name: 'portaria',
    component: Portaria,
    meta: {
        auth: true,
        layout: layouts.navTop,
        tipo: 'portaria'
    },
    children: [
        {   path: 'create',
            name: 'create',
            component: PortariaCreate,
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                layout: layouts.navTop
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Mother route or `Portaria` component will always be shown while accessing any child routes i.e whether you access `/portaria` or `/portaria/create`.

You will see `Portaria` in both the cases, in child route you would see `PortariaCreate` with `Portaria`. 

Try modifying the styles of child, so that you know it is rendering. Currently it might be overlapping with parent component.

Comment: Thanks. Even accessing /portaria/create the child component is not rendered. Only the mother route is rendered.

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: No. No error...

Comment: can you add more code of your complete `routes` file?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5eX677

Comment: Can you move the `children` array below the meta object of `Portaria`?

Comment: I already did that and it doesn't work.

Comment: The code should work technically. 
There is nothing wrong that I can see. As a last resort try changing the `layout` for `PortrariaCreate`. If that does not work, directly put it as sibling route to Portaria and see it works there.

Comment: So it works. Not with children codeshare.io/5eX677

Comment: Ah got it. 
You are missing a `/` when it was inside children. 
It was `{path:'create'...`, it should be `{path: '/create'...`inside children.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Based on what you said. I created a component to load the children. Thank you .

Comment: <template>
    <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Portaria'
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>

Comment: Posted an answer comprising my comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a / when it was inside children. It was `{path:'create'...`, it should be `{path: '/create'...`inside children.

Like so:

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    //base: '/sub-path/',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            alias: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                layout: layouts.navLeft,
                searchable: true
            }
        },
        {

            path: '/portaria',
            name: 'portaria',
            component: Portaria,
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                layout: layouts.navTop,
                tipo: 'portaria'
      },
      children: [
                {   path: '/create', //added / here
                    name: 'create',
                    component: PortariaCreate,
                    meta: {
                        auth: true,
                        layout: layouts.navTop
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
})
```

If above does not work, try changing the layout for PortrariaCreate. If that does not work, directly put it as sibling route to Portaria and see it works there

Answer (score 0):

Your `Portaria` component must contain it's own `<router-view>` for the child routers to display inside.

Nested routes must have matching nested router views.

```
App.vue
 - <router-view>
 Portaria.vue
   - <router-view>
```

If you do not want views inside views then you should flatten your router paths.

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
    //base: '/sub-path/',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        alias: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: {
          auth: true,
          layout: layouts.navLeft,
          searchable: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/portaria',
        name: 'portaria',
        component: Portaria,
        meta: {
          auth: true,
          layout: layouts.navTop,
          tipo: 'portaria'
      },
      {   
        path: '/portaria/create',
        name: 'portaria-create',
        component: PortariaCreate,
        meta: {
          auth: true,
          layout: layouts.navTop
        }
      }
    ]
})
```